# Apache 'In Action' books

Tags: apache

I have the book 'Mahout in Action', and I notice there are also books like 'Hadoop in Action' and 'Lucene in Action'.

Are these considered to be the official text books for these projects, written by developers from the projects? Just wondering if they're 'official' or endorsed by apache or whatever just so I know what I'm referencing.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: ... the books are about programming :)

Really though I'm not sure where to ask a question like this. I looked on the Manning forums, who publish the books. Pretty dead forum!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lucene in Action** seems authoritative to me (if not official) -- I have not heard of anything better. Otis Gospodnetic and Mike McCandless (2 of the authors) are heavy-hitters in the Lucene world.